# Python: Can't pull string from while loop to another function

Tags: python, while-loop, serial-port, pyserial

I have function that includes a while loop that repeatedly reading from serial port.

How do I manage to pull those line to another function without breaking the loop ?

```
def reading_from_serial():
    while 1:
       read_line = ser.readline()
```

Comment: Why do you men by "pull" here?

Comment: I mean to use those read_lines in order to trig another function

Comment: I don't understand that either. Does any of the existing answers solve your problem?

Comment: Actually I havn't tried all of the solution yet. I mean something like "report" in the while loop which passing the current readed line to another function that  will do an action based on specific line

Answer (score 2):

You could do it via queues and multithreading like so:

```
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread


...
queue = Queue()
def reading_from_serial():
    while 1:
        read_line = ser.readline()
        queue.put(read_line)


def output():
    while True:
        new_line = queue.get()
        print(new_line)


Thread(target=output).start()
Thread(target=reading_from_serial).start()
```

The `queue` object could also be supplied as the parameter to both functions.

The argument behind using a multi-threaded approach is that reading from serial port which was stated as a source of data and processing that data in the same thread can easily lead to problems like `TimeoutError` if it would be other sources like for example a file then there would be no issue or if you are absolutely  sure that the processing will be quick.

Comment: You "should" not do this. You _can_ do this obviously, but it doesn't mean you "should", and there are other much simpler solutions.

Comment: @ bruno desthuilliers Please elaborate why not

Comment: As I said: there are other solutions (most being much simpler), and which one is the right one for the OP's needs depends on informations we don't have. What bugs me is the use of "should" (which implies this is "_the_" proper solution) instead of "could" (which implies it's one of the possible solutions).

Comment: @ bruno desthuilliers Fixed the answer. However, in my opinion which I am free to have reading from serial port which was stated as a source of data and processing the lines in the same thread can easily lead to `TimeoutError` other sources are fine serial port not so much.

Comment: You should put this last comment in the answer, to make clear why you specifically suggest using threads here.

Comment: I've tried your solution and now python gives me a NameError referring that one of my global name is not defined (ser). I thought that it's because the definition of this global name existing in a function that not in thread. So I put this function also in thread (3 function total), and it didn't work neither. Do I need to define it sepreatly in every function ?

Comment: There are many solutions to this: 1 you can use the `global` keyword, 2 you can pass `ser` as parameter. 3 You can use a global instance object. If you still have problem edit your question or ask a new one including the instantiation of `ser` object and I will help.

Answer (score 1):

You can create another function and give the line you just read from serial to the function as a parameter:

```
def reading_from_serial():
    while 1:
        read_line = ser.readline()
        process_line(read_line)

def process_line(line):
    print('Processing line:', line)
    return
```

Edit: this solution is as simple as possible, as mrangry777 points out, reading and processing in different threads is better if processing takes longer. If you feel this could be an issue, check out his answer!

Comment: In my opinion you should not process and read lines in the same thread. As it can lead to `TimeoutError` if processing takes too long. Especially from a source like serial port.

Answer (score 0):

You don't give enough details about your concrete use case, constraints and requirements, so there's no definitive answer. One possible solution is mrangry777's answer using threads and a queue, but it's far from being the simplest one. Other possible solutions include

using a callback:

```
def process_line(line):
    # mock
    print(line)

def reading_from_serial(callback):
    while 1:
        read_line = ser.readline()
        callback(read_line)


reading_from_serial(process_line)
```

using a generator:

```
def reading_from_serial():
    while 1:
        read_line = ser.readline()
        yield read_line



def process_line(line):
    # mock
    print(line)

for line in reading_from_serial():
    process_line(line)
```

but you could also use an async task queue like celery or quite a few other solutions I can't think of right now.

Comment: My use is to execute an action in another function based on specific line that appeared in the serial connection. So I need something that continuously reports to the function the current line readed. Hope that this come out more understandable